# Argument type deduction, references and rvalues

Tags: c++, templates, reference, type-inference, rvalue

Consider the situation where a function template needs to forward an argument while keeping it's lvalue-ness in case it's a non-const lvalue, but is itself agnostic to what the argument actually is, as in:

```
template <typename T>
void target(T&) {
    cout << "non-const lvalue";
}

template <typename T>
void target(const T&) {
    cout << "const lvalue or rvalue";
}


template <typename T>
void forward(T& x) {
    target(x);
}
```

When `x` is an rvalue, instead of `T` being deduced to a constant type, it gives an error:

```
int x = 0;
const int y = 0;

forward(x); // T = int
forward(y); // T = const int
forward(0); // Hopefully, T = const int, but actually an error
forward<const int>(0); // Works, T = const int
```

It seems that for `forward` to handle rvalues (without calling for explicit template arguments) there needs to be an `forward(const T&)` overload, even though it's body would be an exact duplicate.

Is there any way to avoid this duplication?

Comment: If you are overloading on lvaluenes like this you deserve to be shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem and the purpose of rvalue references in C++0x. The problem has no generic solution in C++03.

There is some archaic historical reason why this occurs that is very pointless. I remember asking once and the answer depressed me greatly.

Comment: I am one of the people responsible for this sound rule. Deduction of type variables may only calculate value types. "const T" is not a value type. The duplication this requires is not pointless but semantically essential. In case you aren't aware of it, an rvalue never has "const" type, they're actually quite mutable. Dag Brueck of Sweden is responsible for that one, its so you can call g (f(x).modify()) which is needed to properly establish some values.

Comment: @Ytt: What exactly do you mean by "value type" here?

Comment: @Yttrill: Right. So rvalues are perfectly mutable- but they can't bind to mutable references. So if you have `g(f(x).modify())` it's perfectly fine, but you could never have `g(f(x))` where g calls modify itself. I'm not really sure that you're presenting an argument against my suggestion that this state of affairs was ridiculous.

Comment: The type of a value. Basically no top level const or reference. Pointers are values though, so "int const*" is a value type but "int const" is not.

Comment: @DeadMG: Absolutely not, we agree it is ridiculous.

Comment: @Yttrill: So you went for a ridiculous rule to keep on top of another completely ridiculous rule, instead of just fixing the original problem? I'm just trying to understand the mindset here.

Comment: @DeadMG: in my opinion, yes. The problem stems from the untenable type system in the ARM, pre-template. You don't find out how bad your type system is until you try to add polymorphism. Then you should fix it so the polymorphism works. Type systems are understood. What C++ has isn't a sound or consistent type system. It could have been but politics and ignorance got in the way.

Comment: @Yttrill: I think you're missing the point here. The question is not wether cv-qualifiers or reference-ness should be a part of a typename parameter value - the fact is that they are. The question is, given that, what's so essential about rvalues not being deduced "correctly" in this context?

Comment: @uj2: what does correctly mean? They are deduced correctly, but as noted by the OP and in other places, propagation of the information doesn't work. There is no correct way to do it. Note again. There IS NO CORRECT WAY. The type system is inconsistent. You cannot fix an inconsistent system by adding new axioms, the only way to fix it is by removing the conflict. Not enough space in these comments for a fuller explanation.

Comment: Ill try: the problem is that in order to obtain parametric polymorphism, which is required for propagation of types, the type constructors (functions, structures, pointers, etc) must be combinatorial.  As you know, ref and top level const are not combinatorial, therefore they must not be considered as type information (for the purposes of parametric polymorphism). const under a pointer IS parametric: if you write "int const*" it's a proper type. But thats NOT because "int const" is a type. No it is not. The type constructor here is "const*", the base type is plain "int".

Comment: And now you can see: f(T const*) cannot lead to "const const*" in my system because "int const" is not a type. If you double up you get "const * const*". The "const" is a kind of <em>pointer</em>. The committee got the constructor wrong, its as simple as that. "Ref" isn't a type combinator at all, its a storage class.

Comment: If you do it this way, all your non-polymorphic code has the same meaning BUT now templates are parametric. Thats why I say it should never be allowed to bind a template type argument to anything but a value type: that's the requirement for parametricity and that's a requirement for consistent polymorphic semantics. Anything else makes them ugly macros.

Comment: @Yttrill very interesting explanation, thx. Is it possible to avoid the issues with inconsistent type system in modern C++ by avoiding certain language constructs - and if so, which ones? And would such an approach break down the moment one uses the standard library?

Comment: @max: yes, in pure C++ you can avoid problems, and yes, its possible that using a library may reintroduce them (including the standard library). Fundamentally, "const" and "ref" don't work. In the first instance, avoid "ref" by just using pointers. Don't use const at all.  In my compiler Felix, this is what I do, I don't have any problems interfacing with existing C++. I also "cast away const" universally to fix broken libraries. This removes const protection, which is a negative. But it avoids the cost.

Comment: @max: With templates the problem got so extreme the committee introduced the idea of a "declaration type" so that templates could fiddle with const and ref bits of types. This is a hack to allow automation of repairs to a broken type system, which itself is even more broken. Only a template wizard could program with that stuff. Yet polymorphism in good languages like Haskell or Ocaml (or Felix:) is easy.

Comment: @max: the right way is probably to learn enough functional programming so you can chose carefully between functional techniques using values and object oriented techniques using pointers. The hard bit is mixing them, so recognise where and how to mix. Containers are fundamentally objects, but using the values in them is fundamentally functional and the mixing technique is using iterators. Since containers are intrinsically objects they're mutable so you gain little using const iterators: just don't change a container you're iterating over (either writing or insert/delete) even though you can.

Comment: @Yttrill I learned more from your comments to this question than from many full-length blog articles. Do you happen to have anything else written up on this or related topics, by chance?

Comment: @max: well, I redesigned C++ from scratch, resulting my my own programming language Felix http://felix-lang.org, https://github.com/felix-lang/felix. however, the best way forward is probably to learn a more established FPL such as Ocaml, Scala, Clojure, or Haskell since those communities have lots of related publications. Also useful to learn some abstract algebra (esp. category theory), type theory, or whatever maths you can. Functional programming isn't the whole story but its where almost all the research activity is. Wikipedia has lots of good reads.

Answer (score 2):

> When `x` is an rvalue

But `x` is never an rvalue, because names are lvalues.

> Is there any way to avoid this duplication?

There is a way in C++0x:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void forward(T&& x)   // note the two ampersands
{
    target(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Thanks to reference collapsing rules, the expression `std::forward<T>(x)` is of the same value-category as the argument to your own forward function.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this nasty problem with templates *ought* to require duplication because the semantics where a variable is const or not, or a reference or not, are quite distinct.

The C++11 solution to this is "decltype" but it is a bad idea because all it does is compound and already broken type system.

No matter what the Standard or the Committee says, "const int" is not and will never be a type. Nor will "int&" ever be a type. Therefore a type parameter in a template should never be allowed to bind to such non-types, and thankfully for deduction this is the case. Unfortunately you can still explicitly force this unprincipled substitution.

There are some idiotic rules which try to "fix" this problem, such as "const const int" reducing to "const int", I'm not even sure what happens if you get "int & &": remember even the Standard doesn't count "int&" as a type, there is a "int lvalue" type but that's distinct:

```
int x;       // type is lvalue int
int &y = x;  // type is lvalue int
```

The right solution to this problem is actually quite simple: everything is a mutable object. Throw out "const" (it isn't that useful) and throw away references, lvalues and rvalues. It's quite clear that all class types are addressable, rvalue or not (the "this" pointer is the address). There was a vain attempt by the committee to prohibit assigning to and addressing rvalues.. the addressing case works but is easily escaped with a trivial cast. The assignment case doesn't work at all (because assignment is a member function and rvalues are non-const, you can always assign to a class typed rvalue).

Anyhow the template meta-programming crowd have "decltype" and with that you can find the encoding of a declaration including any "const" and "&" bits and then you can decompose that encoding using various library operators. This couldn't be done before because that information is not actually type information ("ref" is actually storage allocation information).

Comment: "and thankfully for deduction this is the case". In the example, `forward(y)` deduces `const int` for T.

Comment: (1) "const int is not... a type"?  It clearly *is* a type in all versions of C++, so I take it you mean it *should not* be a type, in some ideal hypothetical world -- right?  (2) Template argument deduction certainly can infer `const int` or `int&`, don't know what you're on about there.  (3) When you say the solution is "everything is a mutable object", are you proposing a change to the C++ language?  I can only assume so, but I initially thought you were advocating using just a subset of C++ that avoids `const`...

Comment: ... but that won't work for forwarding because `T&` and `T` are now your only possible alternatives, and `T&` can't match an rvalue, while `T` will be deduced as a non-reference type, so it won't work for functions that need to modify the passed-in value.

Comment: "const int" is not a type "despite what the Standard says". So you can't cite the Standard here. It isn't a type. What constititues a type is determined by the theory of types, not by a standards document.

Comment: And no, you cannot infer "const int" from an top level argument. You might if the function was f(T*) called with an int const*, so you're right, I may have mistated the rules. Grrr .. that should be allowed.

Comment: Here's why it should not be allowed: f(T *x) { *x = *x; } called like f(p_const_int) will of course not compile. But there are cases where such instantiations DO compile and do completely the wrong thing. This means templates don't have coherent semantics, that is, they're not parametrically polymorphic. That's necessary if you want to reason about them independently of use.

Comment: @Yttrill: OK, now I understand that you're not using the word "type" the same way I have been.  It would have helped to be specific that you meant an alternate *definition* of "type" from the definition we're accustomed to using when talking about C++.

Comment: I don't follow sorry...  It seems like you're giving an example of a case where the existing C++ rules do the right thing (forbidding compilation), but if you are arguing that the existing C++ rules are wrongheaded (as I believe you are) I would like to see an example of where they *do* fail.

Comment: I must admit that while inferring `const int` is easy, it's hard to get template argument deduction to infer `int&`.  A reference can only ever appear at top-level in a "usual" type, the only exception I can see being as a return value or argument type within a function or function pointer type, so I think the only way to get it inferred would be as part of such a type.  E.g. after `template <typename T> f(void (*)(T)); void g(int&);`, `f(g);` will infer `T = int&`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are k arguments, as I understand it the only "solution" in C++03 is to manually write out 2^k forwarding functions taking every possible combination of `&` and `const&` parameters.  For illustration, imagine that `target()` actually took 2 parameters.  You would then need:

```
template <typename T>
void forward2(T& x, T& y) {
    target(x, y);
}

template <typename T>
void forward2(T& x, T const& y) {
    target(x, y);
}

template <typename T>
void forward2(T const& x, T& y) {
    target(x, y);
}

template <typename T>
void forward2(T const& x, T const& y) {
    target(x, y);
}
```

Obviously this gets very unwieldy for large k, hence rvalue references in C++0x as other answers have mentioned.

Comment: You should never do it so this is never needed.

Comment: @Yttrill: Huh?  It would be very useful to have the ability to forward an arbitrary function call.  See the "Motivating Examples" section at the top of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Of course I agree forwarding is useful. What is not useful is overloading on non-value types. You should NEVER have two functions of the same name where arguments differ only in "const" or "ref" because the semantics are different, so the names should be too.

Comment: Just to ensure understanding: in the OP's example we have precisely this extremely bad practice: two functions called target, one accepting a T& and the other a T const&. I have no sympathy for anyone writing such functions, and therefore none for people trying to use a common template to target one or the other based on its arguments decltype.

Comment: @Yttrill: I agree that overloading on non-value types is a bad idea.  But sometimes you need to be able to forward to an unknown function *whose argument types you don't know* (that is, they could be by-value or by-reference), in which case you still need a perfect forwarding mechanism.  E.g. imagine all the `forward2()` function templates above were methods in a class templated on `U`, which has a member `U u;`, and the calls to `target(x, y)` above were changed to `u.target(x, y);`.  Now we don't know what argument flavour `U::target()` expects, so the 4 overloads are necessary.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: why do you need to do this? You're saying it is OK for me to write crap, and then demand that you forward to my crap. Why can't you just say "NO"? :-) The point is, if you have a function "f" then it either takes a value or lvalue argument, and you can't change that and expect everything to work, anymore than if you changed the name of the function. Or changed the argument from "int" to "int*". Same deal, after all a ref is basically a pointer.

Comment: Just consider f(T) compared to f(T const&), they both bind to rvalues, right? So the change is just a performance thing right, not a semantic change. Right? Wrong. Of course. Values slice. References dont, so virtual function calls will do different things. In your forwarding template you SHOULD be binding only one kind, because the semantics are distinct: this is not a silent change. You shouldn't be ABLE to forward to either. You SHOULD have to write out separate forwarding templates because they're forwarding to semantically different functions.

Comment: @Yttrill: Forget the OP's case in which the target is "hardcoded" into the forwarder -- I'm talking now about a *generic* wrapper or forwarder.  This is the most useful case anyway.  E.g. with Boost Bind, surely you want the same forwarding code to work with both (a) "pure"-type functions that take all their arguments by value and return some value and (b) "state-modification"-type functions that take one or more parameters by reference in order to modify them?

Comment: @Yttrill: How about the tr1/boost::tuple `get` function. It's overloaded exactly like this, and it makes very good sense to me.

Comment: BTW: there's a related and worse problem suggested when you wrote u.target().. (how do you get that nice font?). Dependent names. They shouldn't be allowed either, for the same reason: it destroys parametricity. For example template<class T> void f(T x) { return g(x); } should not compile unless g is polymorphic and in scope. Otherwise you should have to pass g in as an argument. This is not so easy to arrange if it is a method not a global, but that's no excuse for blowing the coherence of templates: it should have been arranged :)

Comment: @uj2: Prefix by saying I don't know much about boost, but from memory the problem only arises because of an underlying stupidity: allowing tuples to have non-value type arguments. So it doesn't make sense to me to allow you to propagate stuff that shouldn't have got in there in the first place (but maybe I don't understand).

Comment: @Yttrill: OK, if dependent names are somehow a *problem* then I think this whole issue has exceeded my reasoning capacity, or I have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere...  I'm not sure how you could get anything useful *done* without them.  (And I'm not sure what you mean by g being *polymorphic* there -- again, the standard C++ usage of "polymorphic" refers to OOP polymorphism via virtual dispatch, but that meaning doesn't make sense to me in this context -- I suspect you again intend a type-theory definition of "polymorphic" instead).  BTW backticks give you the `nice font` :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The best way to see how you can get things done without dependent names is study a language that doesn't have them but still gets things done: Haskell, Ocaml, and my language Felix. If you want to do it in C++ to support OOP you could use a type constraint something like: `template<class T { void g(); }> void f(T x) { x.g(); }` for example. That effectively makes method "g" a parameter.

Comment: Remember: the idea of polymorphic function is that they do things *independently* of the type. Its supposed to work for all types. Such functions only play with the structure around the type, they're not allowed to operate on the type or do anything dependent on the type, unless that operator too is a parameter (eg: you cannot sort an array of T. But you can sort an array of T given a comparator for T as well.

Comment: @Yttrill: Your example makes sense to me, thanks, but I'm having difficulty because I think we're not quite "facing each other": I'm arguing that, *given C++ as it currently is*, there are problems that can be solved by implementing 2^k overloads to use as a perfect forwarder, and that doing this is sometimes the best way to solve the problem *in C++ as it currently is*.  While I think you are arguing that C++'s type system should have been designed in a radically different way that you assert would resolve these problems in a different way, which I don't completely understand :)